# Android-Redirect to activity from javascript(Phonegap/Jquery Mobile)

Tags: android, cordova, jquery-mobile

I have two activities in my android app. MainActivity and SettingsActivity.

MainActivity loads index.html and presents a android menu.I can select settings from menu which will open SettingsActivity. SettingsActivity loads settings.html which has save button.Now what i want is, On successful save of the settings, Application should redirect to MainActivity which in turn will load index.html.

Everything is done, I am just stuck with how to redirect to MainActivity from javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than rolling your own settings activity you may want to take advantage of what Android already gives you. I created a [Application Preferences plugin](https://github.com/macdonst/AppPreferences) that does just that.

Comment: thanks but i want to open settings on click of menu. Your plugin will be loaded through activity after all as it is a html. When user clicks menu and selects settings, at that time i am opening activity, activity loads html from assets/html.

Comment: No, the settings page is all Android Java code. You don't need to call the JavaScript show command of the plugin you can just open the settings page as normal. The benefit of my plugin is you will be able to access the settings values via JS in the index.html of your MainActivity.

Comment: Yes Simon, But i don't want to involve java code in it. I need this same application in iphone and windows phone. I am not familiar with iphone, so i would like to keep all the javascript storage mechanism so that it can operate in those platforms without much change,that is why i want to use as little as possible of java code.

Comment: Then why did you bother with a second Android activity? Seriously, if you are providing a html based settings page and storing the data in localStorage or and webSQL DB then just show and hide the settings page using CSS. Your main and settings pages can be two divs in your index.html. Or you could just navigate to a second page called settings.html.

Comment: Yes, Thanks I am following that now.